# Changing constraints of label

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, constraints

The label text currently structures itself in a weird center column, but I would like for it to stretch out across the screen What changes can I make to the constraints to do so?

[image]

```
func setupViews() {
    self.view.addSubview(lblTitle)
    lblTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive=true
    lblTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
    lblTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive=true
    lblTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive=true
}
let lblTitle: UILabel = {
    let lbl=UILabel()
    lbl.text="Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet picanha porchetta pork   loin short loin turducken biltong."
    lbl.textColor=UIColor.black
    lbl.textAlignment = .left
    lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lbl.numberOfLines=0
    lbl.sizeToFit()
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    lbl.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
    return lbl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the width of the label to 250 with this constraint:

```
lblTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive=true
```

Change that value to what you want the width to be.